# Refresh Listview content after Dialog Closed flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, future

Hello guys am very new to Flutter and trying to learn as much I need before asking anything here,
I have this situation I have Floating Action Button which show a dialog when I choose some options and click on save changes it should close the Dialog and refresh list view depends on my choices here is my code 
Everything works find its call the `getData()` but nothing changed in UI.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:grouped_buttons/grouped_buttons.dart';
import 'package:test/models/Player.dart';
import 'package:test/partials/PlayerCard.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyAppScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppScreenState createState() => new _MyAppScreenState();
}

class _MyAppScreenState extends State<MyAppScreen> {
  List<Player> _players = [];
  String _filters ;
  String filters ;
  String sort ;
  String _sort;

  int _page = 1;
  final String _token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  Future<Null> getData() async {

    isConnected().then((intenet) async{
      if (intenet != null && intenet) {
        var url = 'https://example.com/api';
        final responseData = await http.post(
            url,
            body: {'token':_token,'page': "$_page",'order': filters,'sort': sort},
            headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json"
        });
        //print("$url/$filters/$sort");
        if(responseData.statusCode == 200){
          final data = jsonDecode(responseData.body);
          setState(() {
            for(Map i in data['data']){
              _players.add(Player.fromJson(i));
            }
          });
        }
        _page++;
      }
      // No-Internet Case
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getDatafromSF();
    getData();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        getData();
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: _showFilter,elevation: 8, child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.filter),),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 20.0,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, i){
            if(i == _players.length - 1){
              return loadingView();
            }
            final nDataList = _players[i];
            return PlayerCard(nDataList);
            if (i < _players.length){
              final nDataList = _players[i];
              return PlayerCard(nDataList);
            }else{
              getData();
              return loadingView();
            }
          },
          itemCount: _players.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // method defined to check internet connectivity
  Future<bool> isConnected() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      return true;
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


  Future<bool> _showFilter() async{
    return Alert(
        context: context,
        title: "Filter",
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Order By",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,fontSize: 16),),
            Divider(height: 3.0, color: Colors.black),
            RadioButtonGroup(
              orientation: GroupedButtonsOrientation.VERTICAL,
              activeColor: Colors.blue[800],
              onSelected: (String selected) => setState(() {
                _filters = selected;
                switch(_filters){
                  case "Platinum": filters = 'platinum';break;
                  case "Name": filters = 'name';break;
                  case "Total Trophies": filters = 'total';break;
                  default: filters = 'platinum';break;
                }
                print(filters);
              }),
              labels: <String>[
                "Platinum",
                "Name",
                "Total Trophies",
              ],
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
              picked: _filters,
            ),
            Divider(height: 5.0, color: Colors.black),
            Text("Sort By",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,fontSize: 16),),
            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            ),
            RadioButtonGroup(
              orientation: GroupedButtonsOrientation.VERTICAL,
              activeColor: Colors.blue[800],
              onSelected: (String selected) => setState(() {
                _sort = selected;
                _sort == "Ascending" ? sort = 'asc' : sort = 'desc';
                print(sort);
              }),
              labels: <String>[
                "Ascending",
                "Descending",
              ],
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
              picked: _sort,
            )
          ],
        ),
        buttons: [
          DialogButton(
            onPressed: _savetoSF,
            child: Text(
              "Save Changes",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          )
        ]).show();
  }


  _savetoSF() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('order', filters);
    prefs.setString('sort', sort);
    prefs.setString('orderstring', _filters);
    prefs.setString('sortstring', _sort);
    Navigator.pop(context);
    getData();
  }

  void _getDatafromSF() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //Return String
    String myorder = prefs.getString('order')?? "platinum";
    String mysort = prefs.getString('sort')?? "desc";
    String filterString = prefs.getString('orderstring')?? "Platinum";
    String sortString = prefs.getString('sortstring')?? "Descending";
    filters = myorder;
    _filters = filterString;
    sort = mysort;
    _sort = sortString;
  }
}


Widget loadingView() => Center(
  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      strokeWidth: 10.0
  ),
);
```

Comment: Try to use `setState` when you change something that needs to be rendered.

Comment: @EdsonDota there is already setState in getData() I don't know if this enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem it was all because of Context,Dialog using different context, I solve it by using `StatefulBuilder` so the dialog must be like this

```
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Filter"),
              content: _buildDialogContent,
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                ),
                DialogButton(
                  onPressed: _savetoSF,
                  child: Text(
                    "Save Changes",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```